# Php & Jquery change function

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi folks thank you for reading,

I use a bit of jquery to change the output of a div.

In that div there is a call for a php file, here is the problem only the first php file gets called properly.

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#selectField').change(function () {
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

**HTML and PHP :**

```
     <select id="selectField" class="form-control">
         <option value="option1">Switch1</option>
         <option value="option2">Switch2</option>
         <option value="option3">Switch3</option>
     </select>

            <div id="option1" class="box">
              <?php
              require 'File1.php';
              ?>
            </div>

            <div id="option2" class="box">
              <?php
              require 'File2.php';
              ?>
            </div>

            <div id="option3" class="box">
              <?php
              require 'File3.php';
              ?>
            </div>
```

I have this in the header :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code in file 1 = file 2 but still the output varies.

Comment: Seems to be an issue in your php files. The JavaScript and HTML is correct and works as expected. As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/y1kc3k1z/

Comment: Found the problem , seemed like my other jquery script that helps with showing content based upon the menu kinda stopped doing its thing because the content of the first file got loaded first .
thank you for pointing out its not a jquery flaw :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a fatal error inside your php file.

The javascript is working properly using the code you gave...

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/don/db4qhy0k/

**Code used:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.box').hide();
  $('#option1').show();
  $('#selectField').change(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out its not a jquery flaw :-)